# Alternative for GWT TabPanel .Not working in Development Mode

Tags: gwt, tabpanel

Since Tabpanel doesn't work in Development Mode, it only works in Standard mode. So it means we can't debug our code if we use TabPanel.

so How to make TabPanel from Horizontal or Vertical layout by ourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need not to make any new TabPanel on your own.**

If you see the [docs of TabPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabPanel.html):

> this widget will only work in quirks mode. If your application is in Standards Mode, use [TabLayoutPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabLayoutPanel.html) instead.

So.Please have a look on [TabLayoutPanl](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabLayoutPanel.html).

Comment: Thax u very much Baadshah, ur info save me lo of time.